# Does anyone have any idea how to run an interpolation search on a linked list in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, interpolation

```
void List::searchInterpolation(int id){
Node* low = head;
Node* mid;
Node* high = tail;

int lowest = 0;
int middle;
int highest = getLength()-1;
int counter = 0;

while (low->getDato()->getId() <= id && high->getData()->getId() >= id){
    middle = lowest + (id - low->getData()->getId()) * (highest - lowest) /
        (high->getData()->getId() - low->getData()->getId());
    while (middle != counter){
        mid = low->getNext();
        counter++;
        if (mid->getData()->getId() < id){
            low = mid;
        } else if (mid->getData()->getId() > id){
            high = mid;
        } else{
            cout <<"1"<<endl;
        }

        if (low->getData()->getId() == id){
            cout<<"1"<<endl;
        } else{
            cout<<"-1"<<endl;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Well, that's what I came up with. I've tested it and it seems that there was an infinite loop. It started giving me -1 and 1 everywhere.

Comment: I'm not sure it even makes sense to attempt such a search on a container that isn't random access. You're probably better off with a linear search.

Comment: That's what I've been saying but my college professor wants it done. In fact, everywhere I've searched I haven't even seen any linked list using this.

Comment: Well, you could do it. But you'd have to iterate over the nodes to find your locations. Not terribly efficient. Is your list singly or doubly linked?

Comment: Unfortunately my project has been made in a way that the list can be either singly linked or doubly linked which means I'd have to work with singly linked which complicates things further. The user gets to choose through the interface. Nonetheless, I assume that anything that works on a singly linked list will work on a doubly linked list.

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll have to find the size of your list. This will require a traversal of the list, possibly negating any benefit of the interpolation search unless your comparisons are slow.

Now, use the interpolation algorithm to find the index. Advance `mid` from `low` to that point. Now determine if the target value is less than or greater than `mid` and set `low = mid` or `high = mid` accordingly. Repeat until you've found the target value. You should be able to keep track of the size of the remaining range without having to traverse it again.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this, fortunately a length property was set long before this in order to measure any list that is ever made. However this seems like it will end up been similar to a linear search.

Comment: There's a possibility it could be a little quicker than a linear search. If your list is doubly linked, allowing you to back up if the interpolation algorithm give you a position closer to `high`, that would help. And again, if your comparisons are really slow this might be faster than a linear search.

Comment: I can't do it on a doubly linked, I have to do it in a singly linked list in order to ensure that it will work with both. In this project, we're supposed to make all this stuff work with any type of list.